# Convert UTC time to unix time stamp in C

Tags: c

I need to know the current UTC time and convert it to Unix time stamp.
I tried using combination of `time()`, `mktime()`, `gmtime()` but not getting correct UTC time
Following is the snippet I am using:

```
time_t now;
struct tm  ts;
char buf[80];
now = time(NULL);
ts = *gmtime(&now);
strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%a %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z", &ts);
```

This gives me following output as --> Time :: Sat 2015-01-10 00:14:34 CST which is adding 5 Hr 30 minutes into local time instead of subtracting 5 Hr 30 min.
Can anyone tell me why this is happening ?

Comment: Here is possible solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280051/converting-unix-timestamp-to-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss

Comment: What value are you seeing for `now`? And what is your actual local time?

Answer (score 2):

[edit]  Re-thought the issue.

OP wants a [Unix time stamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).  Such a time stamp is the seconds since Jan 1, 1970.  This is likely nothing more than the below.

```
sprintf(buffer, "%lld", (long long) time(NULL));
```

OTOH, OP also seems to want year-month-day hour:minute:second.  This is not a UNIX time stamp.  It is simply a time stamp which the rest of this answer discusses a portable way to derive.

---

`time()` returns some real type capable of representing time.  It is very often some integer type representing the numbers of seconds since Jan 1, 1970 0:00:00 [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (or [GMT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time)).

```
 now = time(NULL);
```

`gmtime()` coverts `time_t` into a year, month, day, etc. structure for the UTC (GMT) timezone.

```
ts = *gmtime(&now);
```

---

Now comes a coding problem:

```
strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%a %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z", &ts);
```

`strftime()` may ([@Jasen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471930/jasen))  not known the timezone from `&ts`.  Instead, it gets the locale's timezone.  That result is adjusted per the is_daylight_time field `ts.tm_isdst`.  So the following does not make sense.

```
ts = *gmtime(&now);  // UTC/GMT time
strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "... %Z ...", &ts);  // print local standard time name
```

Instead use

```
ts = *gmtime(&now);
strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%a %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC", &ts);
```

---

Consider [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats

```
strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", &ts);
//  2015-01-06T03:51:57Z
```

Comment: ome versions of `struct_tm` incluse  `tm_gmtoff` (int, number of seconds east)  and `tm_zone` which gives a text representation.of the zone.

Comment: @Jasen Edited to include your insightful comment.

Answer (score 1):

The return value of [`time()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/time) already is in UTC:

> time() returns the time as the number of seconds since the Epoch, 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 (UTC).

It's not clear to me why you're doing further processing.

Answer (score 0):

### Fix Your Clock

Your time zone is IST "Asia/Calcutta" (I couldn't find anything else with a 5:30 offset from GMT)

But it's printing as GMT as CST ths suggests that your computers clock is badly misconfigured.

The code you posted works fine here. I cannot provoke it to print CST instead of GMT.

Comment: The code as posted shouldn't have any offset at all. I think there's something wrong with the question.

Comment: As i discovered some versions of strftime can determine GMT for gmtime and some cannot. this seems to be a BSD inverntion.